# Radio type button not working properly

Tags: html, radio-button

My code:

Radio text input type not working properly
  All radio buttons are selected.

```
<input type="radio" name="cash" id="cash" value="CASH"/>CASH<br />
<input type="radio" name="card" id="card" value="CARD"/>CARD<br />
<input type="radio" name="netbank" id="netbank" value="NETBANKING"/>NETBANKING<br />
<input type="radio" name="paypal" id="paypal" value="PAYPAL"/>PAYPAL<br />
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/hw7u83vm/

Comment: there's no php here or if the form is correct, since those tags are missing. Impossible to answer.

Comment: plus, the id's suggests JS

Comment: give same name to all button and just different value.

Comment: The `name` attribute should be the same for each input.

Answer (score 1):

Radios with the same name are treated as a group. When you select one button, all other buttons in the same group are unselected.

Use

```
 <input type="radio" name="type" id="cash" value="CASH"/>CASH<br />
               <input type="radio" name="type" id="card" value="CARD"/>CARD<br />
               <input type="radio" name="type" id="netbank" value="NETBANKING"/>NETBANKING<br />
               <input type="radio" name="type" id="paypal" value="PAYPAL"/>PAYPAL<br />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
           <input type="radio" name="Payment" id="cash" value="CASH"/>CASH<br />
           <input type="radio" name="Payment" id="card" value="CARD"/>CARD<br />
           <input type="radio" name="Payment" id="netbank" value="NETBANKING"/>NETBANKING<br />
           <input type="radio" name="Payment" id="paypal" value="PAYPAL"/>PAYPAL<br />
```

Use this, i have changed the Name to "Payment".
Name should be same

Answer (score 0):

For radio button working properly, You must have `name` property common for all radio buttons

```
<input type="radio" name="payment" id="cash" value="CASH"/>CASH<br />
<input type="radio" name="payment" id="card" value="CARD"/>CARD<br />
<input type="radio" name="payment" id="netbank" value="NETBANKING"/>NETBANKING<br />
<input type="radio" name="payment" id="paypal" value="PAYPAL"/>PAYPAL<br />
```

DEMO : https://jsfiddle.net/md2o2m6x/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow the user to be able to select more than 1 box, use the input type checkbox, but the name attribute must be the same.

```
<input type="radio" name="cash" id="cash" value="CASH"/>CASH<br />
<input type="radio" name="cash" id="card" value="CARD"/>CARD<br />
<input type="radio" name="cash" id="netbank" value="NETBANKING"/>NETBANKING<br />
<input type="radio" name="cash" id="paypal" value="PAYPAL"/>PAYPAL<br />
```

If you want the user to select only one box, use the input type radio, but the name attribute must be the same to make it work properly

CASH
    CARD
    NETBANKING
    PAYPAL